# SwiftUI macOS be notified when NSSearchField comes in and out of focus

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

In my swiftUI application I have an `NSSearchField` that is wrapped inside a `NSViewRepresentable` struct so that it can be used with swiftUI. I need to be notified when the search field comes in and out of focus. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you need to use that for keyboard appearance or what?

Comment: I need to use it to allow the user to paste text into the search field. I have multiple text views that the user can paste text into. I would've thought this functionality comes for free, but apparantly it doesn't.

Comment: You can create your own search field looks like NSSearchField by using NSTextField. It might work.

Comment: But how does that help me determine when it comes in and out of focus? Do *you* know how to detect if a NSTextField comes in and out of focus, but not a NSSearchField?